# How Does the Wilderness Downtown Google Map Work?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, canvas

I was just watching the Wilderness Downtown video - http://www.thewildernessdowntown.com/ - and I couldn't quite work out how the folks behind it did the Google Map which scrolls along and rotates, all on an HTML5 canvas.

I've looked through the Google Maps Javascript API - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/ - and nowhere in it can I see any pointers on how to embed a Google Map into a canvas tag (which can then be transformed as in the video).

Any help on this would be very appreciated,

DLiKS

Comment: Pretty funny that google builds this awesome showcase of HTML5 and doesn't bother to write anything on how they did it.

Comment: @user257493 - google *participating* isn't the same as building the whole thing: http://www.thewildernessdowntown.com/credits.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ricardo Cabello, [Mr.doob](http://mrdoob.com/) in the [credits](http://www.thewildernessdowntown.com/credits.html), has a blog post titled [Making of The Wilderness Downtown](http://mrdoob.com/blog/post/705).

Comment: The closest the blog post comes to explaining how it was done is when it says: 'We couldn't just directly use the embeddable Google Maps, the maps were supposed to have some tilting on the camera so a new Maps Data viewer was required.' However, it doesn't say what this 'new Maps Data viewer' is...

Comment: @DLiKS It was custom built. From the post: "Like with the maps, we had to build a custom Street View Data viewer". I agree, the innards aren't revealed though. But it doesn't sound like they "embedded a Google Map" as you suggest. :)